# Message of the day still show updates are available

Tags: 16.04, updates

I've logged in as root and run

```
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
```

Did a reboot after that.

But, message of the day still shows that I have 7 packages that can be updated.

```
Welcome to Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.13.0-24-generic i686)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com
 * Management:     https://landscape.canonical.com
 * Support:        https://ubuntu.com/advantage

  System information as of Tue Apr 25 12:34:11 SGT 2017

  System load:  0.0                Processes:           116
  Usage of /:   69.1% of 19.56GB   Users logged in:     1
  Memory usage: 50%                IP address for eth0: **
  Swap usage:   0%                 IP address for tun0: **

  Graph this data and manage this system at:
    https://landscape.canonical.com/

7 packages can be updated.
7 updates are security updates.
```

Have tried running `update-motd` and it still shows the same thing.

How do I view and update those packages?

Output of `apt list --upgradable`:

```
linux-generic/xenial-updates,xenial-security 4.4.0.75.81 i386 [upgradable from: 4.4.0.59.62]
linux-headers-generic/xenial-updates,xenial-security 4.4.0.75.81 i386 [upgradable from: 4.4.0.59.62]
linux-image-generic/xenial-updates,xenial-security 4.4.0.75.81 i386 [upgradable from: 4.4.0.59.62]
N: Ignoring file '50unattended-upgrades.ucf-old' in directory '/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
```

Output of `/usr/lib/update-notifier/apt-check --human-readable`:

```
7 packages can be updated.
7 updates are security updates.
```

Comment: Have you tried `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` or `sudo apt full-upgrade` as the updates might be ones that just the regular upgrade cannot run?

Comment: Whats the output of `apt list --upgradable`?

Comment: @heemayl Have updated the output in my post. I suppose I'll have to do the `apt-get dist-upgrade` like @Terrance suggested for those?

Comment: and `/usr/lib/update-notifier/apt-check --human-readable`?

Comment: @heemayl added it to my post too.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to clear this by manually upgrading the linux-headers-generic package:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic
```